# How to distribute package for expo? (.web.js, .js configuration)

Tags: javascript, react-native, webpack, expo, metro-bundler

I want to distribute a package for expo. This package was created while building my app in expo SDK36.

Like many expo dependencies, I use massively the `.ios.js`, `.android.js` and `.web.js` extensions.

While importing a source I have distributed on npm, resolver only import `.js` without any distinction.

As an example [this package](https://github.com/yeutech-lab/react-cookiebot/tree/master/src) should work with expo:

[image]

This is the [`@expo/webpack-config`](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/tree/master/packages/webpack-config) resolved extensions:

```
[
  ".web.expo.ts",
  ".web.expo.tsx",
  ".web.expo.mjs",
  ".web.expo.js",
  ".web.expo.jsx",
  ".expo.ts",
  ".expo.tsx",
  ".expo.mjs",
  ".expo.js",
  ".expo.jsx",
  ".web.ts",
  ".web.tsx",
  ".web.mjs",
  ".web.js",
  ".web.jsx",
  ".ts",
  ".tsx",
  ".mjs",
  ".js",
  ".jsx",
  ".json",
  ".wasm"
]
```

But it does not, I have to manually import by suffixing in my sources with`.web`.

How can I configure `expo` or my distributed package in order to be able to import proper sources for each environment when sources are imported from `node_modules` ?

### Edit

I was wrong to expect my extensions to work with the `main` field of my `package.json`, I have reconfigured my repo with :

```
/home/dka/workspace/github.com/yeutech-lab/react-cookiebot/src
├── CookieBot.js
├── CookieBot.native.js
└── index.js
```

#### Questions  :

1. I have used `.native.js` so my reactjs users (not only expo and react-native users) will import the `.js` file by default
2. Because of *(1)*, others react user's (neither react-native nor expo) don't need some sort of extra configuration to support react-native extensions `.web.js`, `.ios.js`, `.android.is`, `.native.js` and `.js`.
3. In case I do prefer `.web.js` instead of *(1)*, it will not be possible for my react user to do as in *(2)*, and in this case: **what would be the way for them to configure react-native extensions in their project?**
4. For all react-native users, **may I know where the extension can be configured in native projects?** (I believe web project can be configured in webpack with `config.resolve.extensions`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Regarding the main field**

In a node module, you can make the bundler resolve a platform specific "main" file by deleting the file extension in your `package.json`.

```
 -  "main": "index.js"
 +  "main": "index"
```

I would advise against this though as the bundler resolution could work differently in bundlers other than Webpack and Metro. It would be safer to have one "main" file re-export the contents of other platform specific modules (It appears this is what you did in your edit, but I'll leave the explanation here for completeness):

`index.js`

```
export * from './module';
```

- `module.js` Vanilla JS
- `module.web.js` React Native for web
- `module.native.js` React Native

> 3. In case I do prefer `.web.js` instead of (1), it will not be possible for my react user to do as in (2), and in this case: what would be the way for them to configure react-native extensions in their project?

It's important to remember that `.web.js` can still be resolved even if the project isn't a React Native web project. Create React App resolves `.web.js` extensions for every project.

On web, users can configure their platform extensions by modifying the [`config.resolve.extensions`](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/blob/cfb0785744555f34e5b677ef42f4e0f43b6336b0/packages/webpack-config/src/webpack.config.ts#L285) field of the Webpack config. In Expo this can be done by running `expo customize:web`.

> 4. Configure native extensions

This can be done by editing the project's Metro config: [Example](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/5199d6af1aa6dc5d8dfb4a98e675987272d68998/docs/configuration.md#out-of-tree-platforms).

Comment: A well deserved bounty, thanks a lot for this detailed answer. Will you recommend to use CJS or ESM synthax in distributed packages for expo ecosystem? Can we distribute both and how does expo know which one to import?

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa if the name of the package starts with `expo-` or `react-` then ship ESM to get better tree-shaking. This package is really good for creating expo compatible packages: [expo-module-scripts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-module-scripts). Example of a basic universal package: [expo-dark-mode-switch](https://github.com/EvanBacon/expo-dark-mode-switch).

Comment: Excellent Evan, thanks a lot for sharing this. Why having the name to start with `expo-` and `react-` is a good indicator to distribute ESM?

Comment: How can you work in live with the module within another expo project? Do you need to configure webpack alias for all dependencies ? Do you use `npm pack` ?